# pip install django on windows does not download

Tags: python, django, pip, windows-10, virtualenv

i am new to python programming and learning with django. I know the basics and used matplotlib, numby and biopython  for biology but 4 days ago, i was trying to download django using pip install django, pip3 install django but the respond i get is shown in the image below. at first i assumed it was a network problem but it was not. i have the latest version of python and updated pip, Since it would not give me any error codes, i cannot fully understand and i have search multiple time to look for an answer but nothing specific to my issue. I aslo tried running it on a virtual environment but it would not work.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf6Po.jpg)

Comment: can you update image asking because currently it does not show the error.

Comment: update screen shot of your error

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 install django` only works if you have more then one version of python like python 2.0 and python 3 etc installed and you want only 3 to work, did you try just `pip install django`?

Make sure you install your virtual environment

```
py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win

workon myvenv

python -m venv myvenv
```

Make sure you are in correct directory to load your virtual environment

```
PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb>  . myvenv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

You will know when its activated it will look similar to this (myvenv) Then install Django via pip like so

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> pip install django
```

create your project and cd into

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> django-admin startproject myproject
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> ls
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> cd myproject
```

to run local server the folder path should line up

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb\myproject> python manage.py runserver
```